# give focus to textbox when control is shown

Tags: wpf, events, user-controls, textbox, focus

There is a custom UserControl which contains a `TextBox`. How do I give focus to the textbox when UserControl is shown? I've tried calling `TextBox.Focus` on `UserControl.IsVisibleChanged` and `TextBox.IsVisibleChanged` event, but that didn't help. What else can I try?

It seems that something causes `TextBox` to loose focus. The approach that I've mentioned normally works. How can I find out what causes the `TextBox` to loose focus? I've tried listening to `TextBox.LostFocus` event, but it's parameters don't contain much valuable information and I also don't see previous methods in the stack trace.

The code:

```
   void TextBox1_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.TextBox1.IsVisible)
                this.TextBox1.Focus();
        }
```

As I've said before, it works if I use same code on a similar scenario in a test project, but it doesn't work in my application (the application is big and I am basically fixing bugs in it, and this one is amongst them). So I think that the problem isn't that focus is set improperly (as I've thought when I was opening this question), I think that the problem is that something else resets the focus. I am trying to find what it is here: [Find out why textbox has lost focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892081/find-out-why-textbox-has-lost-focus) .

Comment: UIElement.Focus() will work if you try hook it to visibility changed event of your textbox. Can you share some code which might be helpful to undertand your sceanrio?

Comment: Fixed my problem in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892081/find-out-why-textbox-has-lost-focus .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why it doesnt come back on visibility changed... however when I did `TextBox1.Focus()` in `IsEnabledChanged` it worked like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

Use the UC as the bridge, when you let the UC shown, then call some function to focus the `TextBox`.