# Find out why textbox has lost focus

Tags: wpf, events, focus

A textbox looses focus and I don't know why. How can I find out the reason of why the focus is lost? I've tried listening to TextBox.LostFocus event, but it's parameters don't seem to give me any valuable information about the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) - a tool that listens to all events in your app.

You could also try to debug your app with Visual Studio, set a breakpoint in TextBox.LostFocus event handler, and inspecting the call stack, where you might see which method caused the lost focus.

Comment: Awesome tool! I've fixed my problem with it's help.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is it is losing focus because something else takes the focus

You can use the `FocusManager` to find out what control currently has focus. For example, the following line of code will return the control that contains focus for the `MainWindow`

```
FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(Application.Current.MainWindow);
```